# Delete/remove current image from ImageView?

Tags: android, user-interface, imageview

I want to delete/remove or clear image from imageView every time when user again click to set another image to  the imageView. i am getting OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget(Heap Size=7239KB, Allocated=2769KB, Bitmap Size=8748KB)
 here is my code:

```
ImageView imageView;
private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
private String selectedImagePath;
Bitmap yourSelectedImage;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView))
    .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            goToGallery();
        }
    });

}


public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            /*Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "" + selectedImagePath, 1000)
                    .show();
            *///editText2.setText(selectedImagePath);

            // Convert file path into bitmap image using below line.
            yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(selectedImagePath);

            // put bitmapimage in your imageview
            imageView.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);


        }
    }
}

public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
private void goToGallery()
{


    // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
    // select a file
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(
            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"),
            SELECT_PICTURE);

}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Setting a resource to 0 did not work for me. The following did work though:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
```

Answer (score 1):

use the special resource Id '0'. It is not a valid res id, hence the image is blanked.

Answer (score 1):

```
image.setImageDrawable(null);
```

will clear the image in the imageview.

Answer (score 0):

When you set another image to the current `ImageView` the previous one is no longer used for the `ImageView`. Hence, no need to do extra work.

Comment: hey its true but if image is not coming in the another view then what can i do? my problem is in imageview first image is set,after press next button same image is set in the another image.so i wanaa clear that first image.plz help

Answer (score 0):

```
viewToUse.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

- I think using setImageResource with a color identifier will give you crashing issues on Android 2.2.1, make sure to test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
edit_countflag.setBackgroundColor(0);
```